# Plot functions using Matplotlib similar to Matlab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function which plots a figure

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def myplot(x, y):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


myplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
myplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

However after I run the script only one figure shows up, and the second one shows when I close the first figure. I can move `plt.show()` into `main` function which calls `myplot` and this works fine, but I still want a better way, just like `plot` in Matlab. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the answer depends on how you are going to run python, are you running it in a terminal ? or what IDE you are using and how are you running your code from it ? i am guessing it is ran through an interactive session of an IDE like how IDLE runs but that's just speculation.

Comment: If you want to see both lines at the same time then `"the better way"` is to move `plt.show()` into `main`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thank you for response, the ultimate purpose is to import this `.py` as a module. This function has an argument `isPlot`, if `isPlot==False`, returns some values calculated from the input and if `True` plot a figure. I'm running python via VSCode just simply pressing F5.

Comment: @DSPnovice then in that case the first part of my answer will fit your requirements, as it detaches the plot, allowing it to be ran inside any code without restrictions, except on the ability to modify it.

Comment: @furas Thank you. As I commented above, I want to import this function in other script. So if I move the `plt.show()` outside my function, I need import matplotlib in the upper script, which is much more inconvenient.

Comment: if you don't what import `matplotlib` directly then do it in-directly. in you file create function `def show(): plt.show()` - or even `show=plt.show` - and later you have to import `show()` from your file.

Comment: @furas Thank you! That is exactly what I did in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a simple thing, as Matlab is already running a GUI eventloop, while for python ... it depends on the IDE, for example Spyder will run it similar to Matlab as it is running an event loop, while Pycharm / VScode don't allow python to snatch their event loop, and jupyter notebook is running an asyncio server which sends the data to your browser so it can do it but it's not the same as Matlab .... so it depends on your IDE.

now assuming that you are running an interactive session inside your terminal ... or any IDE like IDLE, you can create another process that will be running that eventloop using [loky](https://github.com/joblib/loky), that has to run inside a thread ...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading
from loky import ProcessPoolExecutor
import traceback

def myplot(*args,**kwargs):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=threaded_func,args=args,kwargs=kwargs,daemon=False)
    thread.start()

def threaded_func(*args,**kwargs):
    try:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            res = executor.submit(plotting_func,*args,**kwargs)
            res.result()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        pass

def plotting_func(*args,**kwargs):
    try:
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(*args,**kwargs)
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()

myplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
myplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

this is obviously not perfect as you can only modify your plots inside your `plotting_func`, not inside your interactive code as Matlab does, and while there are ways to get some code working as expected, it really depends on the exact use-case, not a generic code like yours.

for example you can have matplotlib running a temporary eventloop in interactive mode.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()  # activate interactive mode

def myplot(x, y):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


myplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
myplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
plt.pause(5)  # run eventloop for 5 seconds
```

now everytime you want the plot to update you just call

```
plt.pause(5)
```

which will run the eventloop for 5 seconds for you to inspect the plot, and you can interactively modify it like matlab, but this is just a band-aid, and you have to think about writing python code that's not mirrored matlab code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the first part of your answer but `_register_atexit()` in `threading.py` raises a runtime error `"can't register atexit after shutdown"`.

Comment: @DSPnovice check again, i have fixed that issue, it was because you were not running it in interactive mode, i also modified `plotting_func` to act just like `plt.plot` so users can pass in some decorators, but it's up to you to change it